# VUnit test sequential components

Tags: vhdl, vunit

How to test sequential components properly with VUnit testing library and using VHDL? I've been using it to test combinatorial components using `wait for` statements etc. Example of it [here](https://github.com/kazooiebombchu/vhdl-examples/blob/master/components-and-cores/arithmetic/array-multiplier/bit_multiplier_tb.vhd#L25) in my github repo.

Obviously I've to generate a clock signal with `clk <= not clk after half_period;` but how to wait for it? Do I write something like `wait until rising_edge(clk)`. But if I want to advance clock by multiple clock cycles? Is there better way than copy above line multiple times?

Comment: You could always use a for loop. Even better write a reusable procedure to wait multiple clocks (using aloop to wait for the rising edge multiple times) `wait_for_clks(6,clk)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using VUnit you already have such a procedure available. VUnit ships with the OSVVM library for its randomization features but it also contains other stuff, for example [WaitForClock](https://github.com/OSVVM/OSVVM/blob/master/TbUtilPkg.vhd#L186). To enable OSVVM you need to add the following in your Python script.

```
ui = VUnit.from_argv()
ui.add_osvvm()
```

Comment: Thanks didn't know this exist. I wish there would be more tutorials about writing testbenches with VUnit and testing with VHDL in general.

Comment: The best thing to achieve that is probably by being active in the open discussion. Here, in the VUnit forums and elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

I usually have something along this

```vhdl
    procedure walk (
        signal   clk   : in std_logic;
        constant steps : natural := 1) is
    begin
        if steps /= 0 then
            for step in 0 to steps - 1 loop
                wait until rising_edge(clk);
            end loop;
        end if;
    end procedure;
```

Just make sure that if you wait for other signals you might need to re-synchronize with the clock.

For example

```vhdl
    clk <= not clk after 5 ns;
    ...

    wait for 1.5 ns;

    -- This assignment will happen at 1.5 ns, not at a clock edge!
    a <= '1'; 
    walk(clk, 1);

    -- If you need somethign happening at a clock edge and you're not sure of where in
    -- time you are, might be worth synchronizing at the start
    walk(clk, 1);

    --
    a <= '1';
    walk(clk, 1);
    a <= '0';
    walk(clk, 0);
    ...
```

Hope this helps!